# Como resolver un problema el mensaje de "no se ha encontrado la aplicación" al tratar de utilizar javascript en spark ar

Tags: javascript, java, facebook, instagram

Al principio me aparecía un mensaje que decía error en Windows script host, busque soluciones en YouTube y me orientaron a borrar un archivo denominado wscript, al pensar que ya estaría solucionado el error, intente de nuevo utilizar script en spark ar y el mensaje cambio a "no se ha encontrado la aplicación"